# Google map displayed but empty

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to display a Google map - however, the latter isn't filled (no Google's logo is shown, neither the cities, streets, etc.). There's no error in the console. Here is an illustration of the problem:

[image: Google map shown empty]

## Sources

The following code is an extract. Tags like `<body>`, etc. are not shown.

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px;">
            <div style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" id="page-gaz-de-ville-map"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var map;

                $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XYZ', initMap);

                function initMap() {

                    var clusterStyles = [];

                    var mapstyles = [];

                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('page-gaz-de-ville-map'), {
                        styles : mapstyles
                    });
                }

            });
                </script>
```

## Question

It is a fake API key.
Why is the map empty and how can I fix the problem?

Comment: let me know the reason y u down voted to my answer.

Comment: @Varma how do you know that *he* down-voted your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend loading the js file as:

```
<script async defer src=".....key=XYZ&callback=initMap"></script>
```

This should ensure the deferred loading which I guess you were trying to achieve through the `getScript` call.

And define the initMap function at a script element in the head tag. Did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please take the below code,

```
<!--- First of all need to add below script  --->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Your Key&v=3&libraries=places,visualization"></script>

<!--- Below code is used to invoke the google map --->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(64485, 2674827.909);

        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 18,
            zoomControl: true,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng
        });
        myMarker.setMap(map);
    });
</script>

<!--- Html code --->
<div style="width: 600px; height: 400px;" id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score -1):

This is actually You Want. **1st You Must Add HTML, BODY Tags, then Must Import JQuery Plugin ($(document) is JQuery)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var map;
        $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XYZ', initMap);
        function initMap() {
            var myOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(9.981496491854426, 76.30557754516597),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('page-gaz-de-ville-map'), myOptions);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to [generate an api key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).

and replace the XYZ, in javascript call, by your key.